# Using iText on android fonts not being set

Tags: java, android, fonts, itext

I'm creating PDFs in android using iText everything works except fonts in paragraphs, (font works fine in tables)

i declare a font like this

```
 Font titleFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD,18);
```

and set it like this

```
    //create title
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Title");
    p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
    p1.setFont(titleFont);
    //add title to document
    document.add(p1);
```

but i end up with the default helvetica at the default size 12, also if i do the same thing to an element in a table the font works fine so like this

```
    Font paraFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA,14);

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(format.format(cal.getTime()));
    p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    p.setFont(paraFont);
    cell.addElement(p);
```

works perfectly, any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Font size 12 ");
p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
p1.setFont(titleFont);
p1.add("Font size 18");
```

You will notice that the text "Font size 12" has font size 12, and the text "Font size 18" has font size 18. Why? Well, that's the logic in iText 5 and earlier: the font changes at the moment the font changes. That is *after* `"Font size 12"`, and *before* `"Font size 18"`.

Change your code to this:

```
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Font size 12 ", titleFont);
p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
```

Or change it to this:

```
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
p1.setFont(titleFont);
p1.add("Font size 18");
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this really great answer essentially either set it as you instantiate it, or set it before you make the text

Comment: Yes, that the general idea. Thank you for accepting the answer.

Comment: ok this is a really late reply, but Ive only I've just noticed who you are lol thank you very much for all your hard work